# How to write a simple ngrx code in angular for showing and adding an object to array of objects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

How to write a simple ngrx code in angular for showing and adding an object to array  of objects. It is a simple project I have got no service files written. I want to know simple working of store in ngrx.

Consider I have an array of objects I need to add another set of object to this. It should be done using ngrx. Even the view needs to be updated on addition of object.

Comment: Janani, on SO, you need to put your efforts before asking  a question. Did you try to google this ? What results did you get ?  Questions without efforts are likely to be closed. Take a look at https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4/tree/master/ngRx/Employee_DB_Effects which I created few years back. Its  a small code base and will help you understand ngrx. There is new way of writing actions and reducers but the concept remains the same

Comment: @ShashankVivek Hi I have tried doing it following the document in ngrx but I was not successful the product list was not showing up. Some where I have made some error so only asked here. And thanks for replying anyways.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?  What happened when it "didn't work"?  Are you looking for how to set up a reducer that adds an object to an array in the store?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example related to the question I have asked. Hope it helps someone thank you.

https://appdividend.com/2018/01/31/angular-ngrx-store-tutorial-example-scratch/